# Getting Turkish alphabet characters in the URL field in webbrowser

Tags: urls, language

I want to make a WP website in Turkish that shows the proper Turkish alphabet characters in the URL fields in the webbrowser and in WP instead of the English alphabet ones. I tried it already but I don't succeed at it. What happens is, instead of the Turkish characters like these: "Çok güzel bir saksı yapmışlar önümüzdekiler" it shows their 'closest relatives' English character ones, like this: "Cok guzel bir saksi yapmislar onumuzdekiler".

I don't know why this happens and how I can get those proper Turkish characters in the URLs in WP. Anybody have an idea?

How I did it now: I manually installed WP and edited the wp-config.php file to enter my database values and entered these values:

The database character set: I leave it at  utf8, so this:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

DB_COLLATE: I've read that the database collation should normally be left blank except for Turkish language sites which need to have:  'utf8_turkish_ci'. So this:

```
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_turkish_ci');
```

So I did all this on one Turkish language site already but the URL fields still don't show the proper Turkish alphabet characters but instead their closest English alphabet characters.

So I would like to know: What determines which alphabet's characters get to be shown in the URL fields?

And what do I need to do to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

The function `[sanitize_title()][1]` generates slugs. This function makes a subsequent call to [`remove_accents()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents). This function is found in [`/wp-includes/formatting.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1210) and includes a map of all character conversions (just FYI).

This only occurs in the "save" context of `sanitize_title()` which is the default.

Removing accents is not necessary, but it helps ensure the posts slug only contains certain characters. To replace this, you will have to build your own `remove_accents()` that includes Turkish special characters.

**Assuming you've done this and called it `my_remove_accents()`, let's move forward.**

```
function my_sanitize_title( $title, $raw_title ) {
    return my_remove_accents( sanitize_title_with_dashes( $raw_title ) );
}
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'my_sanitize_title', 99, 2 );
```

`sanitize_title_with_dashes()` is added to the `sanitize_title` filter rather than being called from the `sanitize_title()` function. Calling this function does not replace any accented characters.